# C++ Error when changing the cursor from a resource file

Tags: c++, cursor, loadimage, ntdll, resource-file

I'm trying to change the cursor of my mouse with a .cur file in a resource file.

When I'm try my code, I get this error:

> Exception raised at 0x77EB7392 (ntdll.dll) in CleanResourceFiles.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation while reading location 0x00000066.

Here is the code:

```
HCURSOR curs = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR1), 2, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
SetSystemCursor(curs, 32512);
```

Note : `IDC_CURSOR1` is my cursor and `32512` is the ID of the classic arrow cursor. I also included `<Windows.h>` and my `resource.h`.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017, with Win10.

I tried other functions, like `LoadCursor()`. The code above is from "VineMemz".

Finally,  when I tried to change my cursor with `LoadFromFile()` using the path to my `.cur` file, it works.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `LoadImage()`, you are specifying the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag, so the `lpszName` parameter will be interpreted as a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the path to the `.cur` file to load.  But, you are passing in a resource ID number instead of a file path string (I'm assuming `IDC_CURSOR1` is 102 (0x66), which would be consistent with the memory address reported in the error message).  You need to get rid of the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag when loading an image from resources.

Also, you need to pass in the EXE's actual module handle in the `hinst` parameter, not NULL (NULL can only be used with loading OEM-defined images).

Also. you should not be using ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).  The `2` on `LoadImage()` should be replaced with the `IMAGE_CURSOR` constant, and the `32512` on `SetSystemCursor()` should be replaced with the `OCR_NORMAL` constant.

Try this:

```
HCURSOR curs = (HCURSOR) LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR1), IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, 0);
SetSystemCursor(curs, OCR_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's working ! (and sorry if for you it was obvious, but I started learning c++ maybe 4 days ago just for fun, so ty !)